# Overlap in sorting algorithm

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting

Overlap in sorting

The purpose of the program is to iterate through a sequence of integers and identifying the length and order(ascending or descending) of each sequence within the array.
for example given the array of numbers

`[53, 50, 41, 8, 64, 35, 17, 76, 58, 3, 75, 1, 99, 56, 2]`

it is supposed to identify each sequence this being

`[53,50,41,8]` ,
`[64,35,17]`,
`[76,58,3]`,
`[75,1]`,
`[99,56,2]`
sort them to `[8,41,50,53]` , `[17,35,64]`, `[3,58,76]`, `[1,75]` and `[2,56,99]`

but I can only look for the next largest sequence of numbers after sorting the current largest.

here is my code

```
    public static void descendingStructure(int[] x, ArrayList<Integer> y) {

        int descending = 1;

        int maxDescending = 1;

        int descendingRunStart = x.length - 1;

        int descendingRunEnd = x.length - 1;

        
        for (int i = 1; i < x.length; i++) {
            {
                if (x[i] < x[i - 1]) {
                    descending++;

                } else if (x[i] > x[i - 1]) {

                    if (descending > 1) {
                        if (descending > maxDescending) {
                            maxDescending = descending;
                            descendingRunStart = i - descending;
                            descendingRunEnd = i - 1;
                        }
                        descending = 1;

                    }
                }
            }
        }
        if (descending > maxDescending) {

            maxDescending = descending;
            descendingRunStart = x.length - descending;
            descendingRunEnd = x.length - 1;
        }
        if (maxDescending <= 1) {
            return;
        }

        for (int i = descendingRunStart; i < descendingRunEnd; i++) {
            y.add(i);
        }
        sortSubArray(x, descendingRunStart, descendingRunEnd);

        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(x));
        descendingStructure(x, y);
    }
```

[Here is my results after running my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KPrtO.png)

I was expecting an array ordered in

`[8, 41, 50, 53, 17, 35, 64, 3, 58, 76, 1, 75, 2, 56, 9]`

but I got:

`[8, 41, 50, 53, 17, 35, 64, 3, 58, 1, 75, 76, 2, 56, 99]`

Comment: *"but I can only look for the next largest sequence of numbers after sorting the current largest."*: why? What stops you from taking them as they occur, irrespective of their length?

Comment: Why is there `y`? There is no code that *reads* from it.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to think about this problem as operating a [finite state machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine).

### Algorithm

The state consists of five components (let's assume we are examining `x1` with `x0` the previous element and `x2` the following element:

- `was_up` - `x0 < x1`
- `was_down` - `x0 > x1`
- `up` - `x1 < x2`
- `down` - `x1 > x2`
- `ldx` - index of the last sub-sequence

The are only two case we need to differentiate in this state machine. If `was_up` and `down` are true or `was_down` and `up` are true this indicates a change of direction. For this case we will sort the current sub-sequence and then reset to the initial state updating `ldx` to the start of the new sub-sequence.

For all other states, `was_up` becomes `up` and `was_down` becomes down and we continue with the next element.

The following code may illustrate the algorithm more precisely.

### Sample Code

```cpp
#include <iostream>

using std::cout, std::endl;

int main(int argc, const char *argv[]) {
    std::vector<int> data = { 53, 50, 41, 8, 64, 35, 17, 76, 58, 3, 75, 1, 99, 56, 2 };

    int ldx{};
    bool was_up{}, was_down{};
    for (auto i = 0; i < data.size() - 1; ++i) {
        bool up = data[i] < data[i+1];
        bool down = data[i] > data[i+1];
        if ((was_up and down) or (was_down and up)) {
            std::sort(&data[ldx], &data[i+1]);
            ldx = i + 1;
            was_down = false;
            was_up = false;
        } else {
            was_down = down;
            was_up = up;
        }
    }
    std::sort(&data[ldx], &data[data.size()]);

    for (auto elem : data)
        cout << elem << " ";

    return 0;
}
```

### Output

```
8 41 50 53 17 35 64 3 58 76 1 75 2 56 99
```

Comment: This does not answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

Some comments on your code:

- `y` is written to, but never read, so it is useless
- The first loop has no provision for when two consecutive array values are equal, and when this happens, you will get an inconsistent run. I assume here that the decreasing sequences are to be *strictly* decreasing, so the `else` part should not be followed by a condition.
- What you call *sorting* is actually *reversing*. It has the same result here, but the algorithm for revering has a better time complexity than for sorting.
- The main issue you have raised: when a subarray is sorted, it affects the next, recursive execution of the function.
- It is a pity that you have repetition of code just after the loop. Inside the loop you could look at `i+1` instead of `i-1` and detect the last index of a decreasing sequence.
- It is a pity you have to scan the whole array again to find the next decreasing sequence.

I would suggest this algorithm:

1. Collect all decreasing sequences in one loop, but don't reverse anything yet. Just keep track of all the sequences
2. Sort those sequences by their length
3. Perform the reversals of these sequences.

In the first step you could even collect the sequences and use their length as an index in a list and register the starting index in a sublist at that index. That way the second step is no longer needed; looping over this list of lists will give the sequences in order of their size.

Here is an implementation:

```
    public static void reverseSubArray(int[] arr, int first, int last) {
        while (first < last) {
            int temp = arr[first];
            arr[first++] = arr[last];
            arr[last--] = temp;
        }
    }
    
    public static void descendingStructure(int[] arr) {
        List<List<Integer>> startPerRunLength = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>(arr.length + 1);
        // Initialise: for each possible run length, create an empty list of run-start indices.
        for (int runLength = 0; runLength <= arr.length; runLength++) {
            startPerRunLength.add(new ArrayList<>());
        }
        // Detect all runs and register their starting index in the list dedicated to the run length.
        for (int i = 0, runStart = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            if (i + 1 >= arr.length || arr[i] <= arr[i + 1]) {
                // Current index is the last of a descending sequence
                startPerRunLength.get(i - runStart + 1).add(runStart);
                runStart = i + 1;
            }
        }
        // Iterate over the runs in order of their descending size
        for (int runLength = arr.length; runLength > 1; runLength--) {
            for (int runStart : startPerRunLength.get(runLength)) {
                reverseSubArray(arr, runStart, runStart + runLength - 1);
                System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Example run
        int arr[] = {53, 50, 41, 8, 64, 35, 17, 76, 58, 3, 75, 1, 99, 56, 2};
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
        descendingStructure(arr);
    }
```

This outputs:

```
[53, 50, 41, 8, 64, 35, 17, 76, 58, 3, 75, 1, 99, 56, 2]
[8, 41, 50, 53, 64, 35, 17, 76, 58, 3, 75, 1, 99, 56, 2]
[8, 41, 50, 53, 17, 35, 64, 76, 58, 3, 75, 1, 99, 56, 2]
[8, 41, 50, 53, 17, 35, 64, 3, 58, 76, 75, 1, 99, 56, 2]
[8, 41, 50, 53, 17, 35, 64, 3, 58, 76, 75, 1, 2, 56, 99]
[8, 41, 50, 53, 17, 35, 64, 3, 58, 76, 1, 75, 2, 56, 99]
```